# How to Clip InkWell in ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, clip

I have a `ListView` with rounded edges. How can I make the splash from the `InkWell` coincide with the borders of the `ListView`?

**What splash look like now:**

[image]

**My code:**

```
      final borderRadius = BorderRadius.circular(20.0);
      return RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: _refreshList,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, right: 16, left: 16),
          child: DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors.mainGreen,
              borderRadius: borderRadius,
            ),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: borderRadius,
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                reverse: true,
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: state.notes.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final note = state.sortedNotes[index];
                  // TODO(MipZ): Сделать выделение по радиусу
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () => _onNoteTab(note.id),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                            note.mood.selectedIcon,
                            height: 50,
                            width: 50,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 13),
                          //Расстояние между иконкой и информацией
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                _MoodRow(note: note),
                                _SleepAndFoodRow(note: note),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

I need this white splash to be along the border of the `ListView`.

Comment: I'm not sure which part of the image is the splash and the border that you want to clip, can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. At the top, where the green border ends (just where the emoji gets cut off), the gray color is the splash from the inkWell. It shouldn’t be like this, I would like the splash to end right on the green border.

Answer (score 3):

Add `borderRadius` property to `InkWell` for radius of ink effect

```
return InkWell(
            borderRadius: borderRadius, // add border radius
            onTap: () => _onNoteTab(note.id),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    note.mood.selectedIcon,
                    height: 50,
                    width: 50,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 13),
                  //Расстояние между иконкой и информацией
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        _MoodRow(note: note),
                        _SleepAndFoodRow(note: note),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But if I add this property for inkwell, then each object in my ListView will have a rounded splash, which is not exactly what I need. Because my ListView has rounded borders only at the top and bottom. And if I scroll up a little, the splash will go beyond the boundaries of the item. 
Anyway thank you to find time to answer me!

Comment: you can either use GestureDetector or make highlightColor and splashColor of InkWell transparent to remove ripple effect (Just workaround for the issue)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing `ClipRRect` with `Material`? Literally just that word, since `borderRadius` also works for `Material`.

The way it works is that splashes of an Inkwell are drawn on the underlying `Material`. By having the `ListView` wrapped in one the splash shouldn't be able to go outside it.